# How to add additional information about a crash in Mobile Center

Tags: xamarin, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I develop a Xamarin.Android application and I use Xamarin.Insights to get information about crash or errors that happen.

I am migrating this project to Mobile Center, thanks to that video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_uOgl-sO5A&t=680s).

I would like to know how to add additional information about a crash during a crash report.
For instance, I would like to know if the user is connected to wifi or not, or the identity of the user, or anything else.
Or I would like to report an error in a try catch with information about the Exception catched and actual values of variables used at this time.

With Xamarin.Insight, it's very easy :

```
string sAdditionnalInformation = exc.Message + sTitle + sDescription;
Insights.Report(exc, sAdditionnalInformation , Insights.Severity.Error);
```

How could I do this with Mobile Center please ?

I have seen the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/sdk/crashes/xamarin

I know there is the method below to report a crash manually, but I can't add additional information :

```
Crashes.GenerateTestCrash()
```

I have seen the event below, but I don't know how to add additionnal information with that. I did not found any documentation about that.

```
Crashes.SentErrorReport
```

Any help would be really appreciated please :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is currently not yet supported by Mobile Center but on their Roadmap, see the "Crashes" section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/general/roadmap

> **Crashes**
>
> - Display of attachments sent from the Crashes SDK, in the portal

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lukas !